# DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName not grabbing channel in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Using DomDocument to fetch RSS feeds but have run into an odd issue. If I grab some RSS feed like http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot it works fine. However, an RSS feed I am trying to parse is giving me issues: http://www.ryanhache.com/feed

It seems to not be able to find the channel tag and then loop through that. The functions I've inherited are as follows and called with RSS_Retrieve($url). WHat am I missing in these functions or is there something wrong with the feed I am pulling?

```
function RSS_Tags($item, $type)
{
    $y = array();
    $tnl = $item->getElementsByTagName("title");
    $tnl = $tnl->item(0);
    $title = $tnl->firstChild->textContent;

    $tnl = $item->getElementsByTagName("link");
    $tnl = $tnl->item(0);
    $link = $tnl->firstChild->textContent;

    $tnl = $item->getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
    $tnl = $tnl->item(0);
    $date = $tnl->firstChild->textContent;

    $tnl = $item->getElementsByTagName("description");
    $tnl = $tnl->item(0);
    $description = $tnl->firstChild->textContent;

    $y["title"] = $title;
    $y["link"] = $link;
    $y["date"] = $date;
    $y["description"] = $description;
    $y["type"] = $type;

    return $y;
}

function RSS_Channel($channel)
{
    global $RSS_Content;

    $items = $channel->getElementsByTagName("item");

   // Processing channel

   $y = RSS_Tags($channel, 0);      // get description of channel, type 0
   array_push($RSS_Content, $y);

   // Processing articles

   foreach($items as $item)
   {
       $y = RSS_Tags($item, 1); // get description of article, type 1
       array_push($RSS_Content, $y);
   }
}

function RSS_Retrieve($url)
{
   global $RSS_Content;

   $doc  = new DOMDocument();
   $doc->load($url);

   $channels = $doc->getElementsByTagName("channel");

   $RSS_Content = array();

   foreach($channels as $channel)
   {
       RSS_Channel($channel);
   }

}
```

Comment: Your `http://www.ryanhace.com/feed` url appears to be 404?

Comment: Bah mispelled the URL: http://www.ryanhache.com/feed

Comment: Seems ok here. What is your actual output and your expected output?

Comment: Well the code works on other RSS feeds but for this particular one it doesn't seem to enter the loop inside RSS_Retrieve that calls RSS_Channel - so $channels is empty.

Comment: What I am saying is, I ran your code, with the url you specified, and `$channels` is not empty and the `$RSS_Content` var looks correct (it has `type=0` elements in it). In other words, it appears to work fine.

Comment: I'd say you need to deal with XML Namspaces here.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work, but the task can be accomplished much more simply and without using a global variable.

```
function RSS_Tags($node, $map, $type) {
    $item = array();
    foreach ($map as $elem=>$key) {
        $item[$key] = (string) $node->{$elem};
    }
    $item['type'] = $type;
    return $item;
}

function RSS_Retrieve($url) {
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $elements = array('title'=>'title', 'link'=>'link',
        'pubDate'=>'date', 'description'=>'description');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->channel as $channel) {
        $feed[] = RSS_Tags($channel, $elements, 0);
        foreach ($channel->item as $item) {
            $feed[] = RSS_Tags($item, $elements, 1);
        }
    }
    return $feed;
}

$url = 'http://www.ryanhache.com/feed';
$RSS_Content = RSS_Retrieve($url);
```